# Using ATX 24-pin PSU (Corsair VS450) on 945GCM3 (24-pin + 4-pin Motherboard)

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

I have a PC with Jetway 945GCM3 motherboard, Intel E4500 Processor, 3GB RAM and ATI HD4670 Graphics Card. The PSU suddenly started giving troubles and I decided to replace the PSU. The older PSU had a 20-pin + 4-pin auxiliary power connector on it. The new PSU I bought (Corsair VS450) only has 24-pin ATX connector.

I wasn't aware (didn't give much thought about) all these differences in pin before ordering the PSU. Only after unboxing and trying to connect it, did I come to know that the PSU doesn't have the 4-pin connector.

Now, since the 4-pin is just to provide auxiliary power, is it safe to ignore it and power on the system with just the 24-pin connected?

**My system components:**

- Intel E4500
- Jetway 945GCM3
- 3GB DDR2 RAM (1GB + 2GB)
- 500 GB 7200 RPM HDD
- HIS HD4670 512 MB
- (No floppy or DVD drives)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A newer PSU will likely have a 6 or 8-pin instead of the old 4.
Sometimes they are splittable, like the 20/24 ATX connector, sometimes not

The first 4 pins will still fit an older motherboard... & will only fit one way.
Don't run it without the 6/8/4-pin in place.

According to the Corsair site, that PSU definitely has an EPS connector, though I can't find a pic that shows it

Comment: Thanks, how bad that I didn't realize the 8-pin connector is actually splittable (4+4)!

Answer (score 1):

Your motherboard only requires two power connections, the 24-pin main power connector and a 4-pin 12V connector for the CPU:

[image]

As long as you make **both of these connections** it will be safe to power on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

The 8-pin on the PSU splits into two 4-pin connectors.  Simply take the 8-pin, split it in half and plug in the 4-pin that fits your motherboard.